# Reliable & scalable solutions for live audio streaming?

Tags: audio, streaming, live, audio-streaming

I wonder if you could share your thoughts / resources about live audio streaming (to run on-line radio station). I have to admit, I am a complete newbie to the subject, so please excuse me lack of details.

What are the most recommended platforms / software setups?

Opinions based on personal experience would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Similar question with helpful answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390127/how-to-stream-semi-live-audio-over-internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reliable ones are:

- [Shoutcast](http://www.shoutcast.com/)
- [Icecast2](http://www.icecast.org/)

Shoutcast may crash from time to time if You try to switch the introfile on the run. See the [icecast2 vs shoutcast performance comparsion](http://www.icecast.org/loadtest.php). There are many easy-to-use tools like sc_trans or winamp's DSP shoutcast plugin that You can easily configure to start streaming Your own radio on those servers. See [here](http://shoutcast.com/download) and generally browse on the topic, there are lot of guides on how to start Your own radio.

Both Icecast2 and Shoutcast can serve several thousands of clients with no problems (I had it on production on heavy load for years).

Answer (score 0):

[Shoutcast](http://www.shoutcast.com/) has always worked well for me. I know a few others that use it as well. Reliable and fast.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it doesn't provide live audio encoding, does it?

Comment: I believe that the sound source is up to you. Shoutcast is just the server. If you want to stream live content then the player you use to stream music to the server (which then streams it to users) must support that feature.

Comment: Sure, obviously that's the feature I'm looking for.